# Find a property of a sibling control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Windows 10 Pro 64, VS 2019 Community, WPF App

I have an app that has a UserControl with two members, each of which is a UserControl that contains a header which is 2 -3 lines of text, with a ListBox below it.  My objective is to set the height of the one header to the height of the other, and I've chosen to bind the one to the other to accomplish that.  But, it appears as if my RelativeSource is not resolving, which results in trying to set the height to a NaN, which, of course, does not change it.  I've tried many different ways to express the RelativeSource, and none of them has worked.  Here's the latest:

Here's the main window:

```
    <Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <local:MyParentControl x:Name="Daddy"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the Parent control that contains the two children:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.MyParentControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <local:MySonControl x:Name="Sonny"/>
            <local:MyDaughterControl x:Name="Girlie"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The first child control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.MySonControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="Header">
                <TextBlock Text="Vertical space" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Sonny's Stuff" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Column A" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Column B" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Column C" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <ListBox x:Name="Stuff"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the second, which contains the binding statement:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.MyDaughterControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="Header"
                        Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MyParentControl}, Path=Sonny.Header.ActualHeight}"
                        >
                <TextBlock Text="Girlie's Stuff" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Column A" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Column B" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Column C" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <ListBox x:Name="Stuff"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have not touched the code-behind, it's just as VS generated it.

Here's what it displays:

[image]

What we *should* see is that the right header is the same height as the left, but as you can tell, that is not the case.

I get the following error message in my output window, which I take to mean that it's not resolving the RelativeSource:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Sonny' property not found on 'object' ''MyParentControl' (Name='Daddy')'. BindingExpression:Path=Sonny.Header.ActualHeight; DataItem='MyParentControl' (Name='Daddy'); target element is 'StackPanel' (Name='Header'); target property is 'Height' (type 'Double')
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: _"My objective is to set the height of the one header to the height of the other"_ -- seems reasonable. _"I've chosen to bind the one to the other to accomplish that"_ -- not reasonable at all. You should not try to bind properties of one UI object to those of another. Instead, prefer the rich array of built-in layout mechanisms that WPF provides. There are a number of different ways you might use those to accomplish your goal, and the one posted answer seems to me to be a good choice. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a SharedSizeGroup to sync the heights of the rows, and remove the StackPanels in favor of Grid rows:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="HeaderGroup"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Girlie's Stuff" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
         <TextBlock Text="Column A" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
         <TextBlock Text="Column B" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
         <TextBlock Text="Column C" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
     </StackPanel>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="3" x:Name="Stuff"/>

</Grid>
```

```xml
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="HeaderGroup"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Vertical space" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Sonny's Stuff" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Column A" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Column B" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Column C" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="3" x:Name="Stuff"/>

    </Grid>
```

```xml
 <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <wpfApp2:MySonControl x:Name="Sonny"/>
         <wpfApp2:MyDaughterControl x:Name="Girlie"/>
     </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
```

Results in:

[image]

Depending on what the contents of the two child control will be, I strongly suggest to only use one child UserControl and use MVVM to populate it with different data. This will remove the need to maintain two basically identical controls.